# append value to href using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I basically have a field element with name="one".As soon as I fill the field,the value should be appended to an href    `<a name="number" href="example.php" </a>` .

It should append it in the format `href="example.php?number=one"` after i fill the field.Is this possible?Im new to jquery.

I have this for getting the values in the jquery

```
var num = $("[name='number']").val();
```

but the rest,appending things,im not sure how to do that.Any help?

Comment: Do you need to allow the href to be appended multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var $a = $('a[name="number"]');
//store the original value so that we can handler multiple changes
$a.data('href', $a.attr('href'))
$("#one").change(function () {
    $a.attr('href', $a.data('href') + '?number=' + this.value)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6ST8W/)

Note: This solution does not support handling values from multiple input elements

Comment: +1 Arun your are at highest position as usual :D. Cheers

Comment: @Arun Thanks for this.Works like a charm :) Can i ask you one doubt,what if,if im having multiple another input field such as name.     ie www.example.com?number=123&name=ahs    ?

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado that is good as long as it is added as a comment so that it can be rectified... but I don't think it is TJ because he always says what is the problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny I do not understand why other people getting envious. It happens to me also today two times :(

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Correct. I almost always comment without downvoting, and rarely downvote without commenting.

Comment: Oh is there any solution for that?@ArunPJohny

Comment: The second time works well, he's storing with `data`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder we are storing the original href... so it should be fine.. did you check the fiddle

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Nice, sorry, missed the `data` bit! But what about hrefs with query strings already? You're adding a second `?`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that case is not handled... what is your opinion about the second question from OP (about multiple inputs ) http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6ST8W/3/ or will you go for a regex based replace

Comment: @ArunPJohny: FWIW, looks good to me, other than the `?` thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I let it intentionally... can handle it if OP comes up with that case

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
var $a = $("a[name=number]"),
    href = $a.attr("href");

$a.attr("href", href.split('?')[0] + "?number=" + num);
```

Cheers

Comment: What about other query string params? This just throws them away.

Comment: Right. To the question, the answer.

Comment: It's a half-answer at best.

Comment: //offtopic TJ is killing you all :D

Comment: @RoyalBg: I'm just commenting on obvious errors. I mostly comment without downvoting, but a couple of the answers here were *really* "not useful" and so downvoting those answers was appropriate. This *was not* one of them. I doubt I've ever had reason to downvote an answer from Edgar.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ETsA8/5/

**Html :**

```
   <a name="number" href="example.php">ss </a>
    <input id="one" type="text" >
```

**Js:**

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    var link = $("[name='number']").attr("href");
    $("#one").change(function(){
        var a_href = $("#one").val();
        $("[name='number']").attr("href", link+'?number='+a_href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a[name="number"]').attr(href(function(i, oldhref) {
    return oldhref + '?number=' + value;
});
```